# ¿Cómo puedo saber desde dentro un proceso, si los demás procesos han terminado?

Tags: java, algoritmos, hilos, clase

Me explico, tengo 3 clases P, Q y R que heredan de Thread con su propio método `run()`, lanzo 3 hilos (1 para cada objeto de cada clase). Ahora, quiero que cada hilo ceda el turno a otro hilo, pero claro, necesito saber si el hilo al que se le va a ceder el turno no ha terminado, ya que si se lo cedo sin comprobar esto, este proceso nunca cederá su turno.

¿Como puedo comprobar antes de ceder el turno a un hilo, si ese hilo ya ha acabado?

```
public class algDekker {
    /* Iteraciones que dará cada hilo */
    static final int iteraciones = 2000000;
    /* Recurso compartido */
    static volatile int enteroCompartido = 0;
    /* Representa el deseo del hilo P de entrar en la seccion critica */
    static volatile boolean wantp = false;
    /* Representa el deseo del hilo Q de entrar en la seccion critica */  
    static volatile boolean wantq = false;
    /* Representa el deseo del hilo R de entrar en la seccion critica */  
    static volatile boolean wantr = false;
    /* Representa de quien es el turno */
    static volatile int turn = 1;

    /**
    * Clase que modela un proceso cualquiera P
    * 
    */
    class P extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<iteraciones; ++i) {
                /* Seccion no critica */
                wantp = true;
                while (wantq || wantr) {
                    if (turn == 2 || turn == 3) {
                        wantp = false;
                        while (turn == 2 || turn == 3)
                            Thread.yield();
                        wantp = true;
                    }
                }

                /* Seccion critica */
                ++enteroCompartido;
                /* Fin Seccion critica */

                turn = 2;
                wantp = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Clase que modela un proceso cualquiera Q
    * 
    */
    class Q extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<iteraciones; ++i) {
                /* Seccion no critica */
                wantq = true;
                while (wantp || wantr) {
                    if (turn == 1 || turn == 3) {
                        wantq = false;
                        while (turn == 1 || turn == 3)
                            Thread.yield();
                        wantq = true;
                    }
                }

                /* Seccion critica */
                --enteroCompartido;
                /* Fin Seccion critica */

                turn = 3;
                wantq = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Clase que modela un proceso cualquiera R
    * 
    */
    class R extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<iteraciones; ++i) {
                /* Seccion no critica */
                wantr = true;
                while (wantp || wantq) {
                    if (turn == 1 || turn == 2) {
                        wantr = false;
                        while (turn == 1 || turn == 2)
                            Thread.yield();
                        wantr = true;
                    }
                }

                /* Seccion critica */
                ++enteroCompartido;
                /* Fin Seccion critica */

                turn = 1;
                wantr = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Constructor de algDekker
    */
    algDekker() {
        Thread p = new P();
        Thread q = new Q();
        Thread r = new R();
        p.start();
        q.start();
        r.start();

        try {
            p.join();
            q.join();
            r.join();
            System.out.println("El valor del recurso compartido es " +  enteroCompartido);
            System.out.println("Deberia ser 2000000.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new algDekker();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sospecho que hay mejor respuesta para tu pregunta. Aunque ya aceptastes una respuesta, si incluyes tu código, de seguro podrás recibir una respuesta mas precisa para tu situación. También, considera modificar tus clases para *no heredar* de la clase `Thread`. Mas bien, deberías usar la interfaz `Runnable`. Es mejor práctica.

Comment: He añadido el código que tengo, debe de haber alguna forma de hacerlo sin llamar a `isAlive()`, simplemente añadiendo variables y estructuras de control oportunas para hacer lo que quiero. Uso la clase `Thread` porque me exigen que la use, está claro que implementar `Runnable` es mejor práctica ya que me permite heredar, si uso `Thread` ya me restringe. Gracias

Comment: Hmm. ¿Se trata de un ejercicio? Porque por el nombre de la clase, parece que estás tratando de usar el algoritmo Dekker. Pero ese algoritmo no está diseñado para mas de 2 hilos. ¿Cuales son tus instrucciones? ¿Qué herramientas puedes usar, y cuales no? Además, creo que la pregunta principal está mal formulada. No parece que quieres saber cuando un hilo ***terminó del todo***, sino cuando ***terminó su turno***. Eso es muy diferente y creo que invalida la respuesta aceptada. Tal vez valga la pena abrir una nueva pregunta con la pregunta aclarada y todos los detalles pertinentes.

Comment: Quiero saber si un hilo terminó del todo, ya que si le paso el turno a ese hilo y ya ha terminado, nunca cambiará el turno de nuevo por lo que el programa nunca termina, que es lo que me está pasando. Ya sé que no funciona para más de dos procesos, pero tengo que hacer lo que pueda y analizar por qué no funciona para más de dos. Aun así, la pregunta es independiente al ejercicio. Quiero saber qué variables me permitirían saber si un hilo ha terminado si ejecución para no pasarle el turno y que no se me bloquee el programa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar el método `.isAlive()`. Eso te dice si está corriendo o no.

Comment: Claro, mi duda es, si están en tres clases diferentes, ¿a qué le hago .isAlive()? Porque los objetos que lanzan los hilos están en un main y no puedo usarlos en una de las 3 clases, sólo puedo hacer this, cosa que no me sirve de nada.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Para hacer eso que nos cuentas tendrás que tener una parte del código que los lance, un "Manager". Ese es el que debe ir dando paso a los tres hilos teniendo uno activo y preguntando a los otros para pasar el relevo o lo que quieras hacer. El caso es que tu pregunta era cómo pregunto si un hilo ha acabado. Si tienes otra pregunta ponlo más claro y añade el código que tengas.

Comment: Vale, estructuraré de otra forma el programa para plantearlo como has dicho.
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

tu clase main esta mal

tu clase main solo tiene que innicializar tu programa y no meterse con la logica de tu programa

refactoriza esa parte y veras que podras solucionar tu problema

Comment: Perfecto, haré eso entonces, reestructuraré el programa para poder hacerlo.
Gracias